# Next js redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage

Tags: javascript, next.js, redux-persist

I'm trying to configure `redux-persist` in my nextjs project I basically tried everything and I keep getting this message "Next js redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage"

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist"
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"
import cart from "./cartSlice"

const reducers = combineReducers({ cart })

const config = {
key: "root",
storage,
}

const reducer = persistReducer(config, reducers)
const store = configureStore({
reducer: reducer,
devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
middleware: [thunk]
})

export default store
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.